# Acer Aspire Windows 8.1, Screen goes black when unplugging external monitor.

Tags: windows, display

I have an issue with my laptop screen. As soon as I unplug the external monitor, it goes black. I've tried using the Fn F5 combination to set it to only one screen but it won't do anything to fix the problem. Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I resolved the problem of the screen going black when I unplug the laptop from the charger.

- Go to the desktop, then click on the "battery" picture on the bottom
  right-hand side of the screen.
- From there you can select Balanced or Power Saver options. Click on
  "more power option".
- For both Balanced and Power Saver, click on Change Plan Settings.

Most likely the brightness has gotten turned off for the Battery power option (in both plans).  Adjust the brightness and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your model, but some laptops have a specific button to switch between external and native displays. Maybe look at the manual for you laptop.

Answer (score 0):

It should only go black for a second and come back. If not; you will want to locate a button (probably around the function keys) that has something to do with 2 rectangles (monitors) and press it a few times when the screen goes black.

As it has been stated that you have tried this. Make sure that you do it when the monitor is unplugged.

Comment: OP notes he has used the Function key combo to manage the internal/external displays

Comment: the display button isn't a fn+ combination on all laptops. some are just the button.

Comment: Function keys as in F1-F12.

Answer (score 0):

As jmc302005 says, the resolution to the problem may be different depending upon your computer, but I found that when my screen goes black, you can close the lid for 10 seconds and reopen it, and everything will be back to normal. It seems a rather simple solution, but it took me two months to figure out.